# Бинарное представление строки

Tags: bash

Можно ли как-то в bash строку перевести в бинарное представление (и обратно) без посимвольного перевода в октеты? Или для этих целей все же проще воспользоваться перловыми pack и unpack? Да, я имею в виду решение в одну строку.

Comment: Добавте пример входных данных и ожидаемого результата.

Comment: И уточните, что значит «перевести в бинарное представление».  Вы про *Base64* или что-то ещё?

Comment: @Ainar-G, *base64* как раз **небинарное** представление **бинарных** данных.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по упомянутым в вопросе `pack` и `unpack` в контексте `Perl` подразумевалось, наверное, следующее:

```
perl -lpe '$_=unpack "B*"' <<< 'некая строка' | perl -nE 'say pack "B*", $_'
```

где левая часть конвертирует `некая строка` в строку из нулей и единиц, а после ее передачи далее по конвейеру она снова приводится к `некая строка`. Если это так, то однострочник для конвертирования в подобное представление можно представить как:

```
xxd -b <<< 'некая строка' | grep -oP '[01]{8,}\s' | tr -d ' \n'
```

`xxd -b <<< 'некая строка'` возвращает бинарное представление символов с оффсетами, далее `grep`'ом забираем октеты и объединяем их командой `tr -d ' \n'`.

Обратное действие немногим сложнее:

```
fold -8 <<< '11010000...' | xargs -i bash -c 'printf %b `printf "\x%x" $((2#$1)) 2>/dev/null`' - {}
```

Здесь мы бьем строку на октеты `fold`'ом, каждый из которых `xargs`'ом приводим к исходному состоянию. Нужно взять во внимание, что `xxd` поставляется с `vim`, так что пример может и не сработать, а потому лучше скорее всего действительно использовать `Perl` или какой другой язык программирования имеющийся в системе. Например, `Ruby` чем-то похож на `Perl`:

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_.unpack("B*")' <<< 'некая строка'
ruby -ne 'puts [$_].pack("B*")' <<< '11010000...'
```

И так далее.